# Cosa significa "uccello primavera"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Verso sera, in pegno di amicizia, il bambino regalò a Candida un **uccellino primavera**. Aveva le ali nere, il petto giallo e una testolina rotonda e piumosa. 
>         Albina la trovò che gli lisciavano le piume. Le strappò di mano l'**uccello primavera**, lo osservò per un attimo, poi lo scagliò via.

Ho cercato alle voci "uccello" e "primavera" di alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna spiegazione sul significato di "uccello primavera". Tuttavia, una ricerca su Google di questa espressione, ne dà parecchie occorrenze. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire? Potrebbe trattarsi di un uccello migratore che si vede soltanto durante la primavera?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Ma questa espressione si trova su parecchi siti web. Un esempio: https://lombradelleparole.wordpress.com/tag/alluccello-primavera-poesia-di-uwe-gresmann/. E, per quanto riguarda il lessico, finora non ho trovato niente sul romanzo che si possa qualificare di inventato dall'autrice.

Comment: Ho trovato [questo articolo](http://sora.unm.edu/sites/default/files/journals/wilson/v099n02/p0218-p0232.pdf) in inglese in cui appaiono frasi come, per esempio, "Edges of clearcut stands were avoided by winter birds but were used extensively by spring birds". Non so se questi "spring birds" sarebbero "uccelli primavera" in italiano.